# How to fix this login page isn't working in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I created a login page using mysql with user role, but login page not working/not loading.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
      include "config.php";
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $stmr = db->prepare("SELECT * FORM login WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, username);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $user = $row['username'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $type = $row['type];
        if ($username==$user && $pass==$password) {
            session_stat();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
            if($type=='Member'){
            ?>
            <script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>
            <?php
            } else {
                ?>
            <script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>
            <?php
            }
           } else {
              ?>                 
             <strong>Oops!</strong> You Can not Not Visit This Page.
             </div>
            <?php
           }
        }
      ?>
```

I don't understand where is the problem. Please help me to solve this problem.

____ Advance Thanks And All The Best.

Comment: Does an error appear?

Comment: `$row = $stmt->fetch();` will fetch a single record

Comment: This error: The mydomain.com page isn’t working

mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Error on this line : `$type = $row['type];` you missed the closing single quote

Comment: Please don't use `md5()` is no longer secured use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: $type = $row['type]; you missed single quote at the end. and why are you using this condition `  if ($username==$user && $pass==$password) {` just check count if you get 1 then user exists and do the rest code.

Comment: Please use proper Editor like sublime or something else that you want. So you no need to worry about that syntax error like this

Comment: Error also here : `$stmt->bindParam(1, username);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, password);`

Comment: where error on $stmt->bindParam(1, username); ?

Comment: you are not binding `username` you are binding `$username`  username is undifined

Comment: $stmr = db->prepare() error here

Comment: add this line on top of your page `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);` you willl see all your errors

Comment: you are also binding your parameters on a wrong variable

Comment: `SELECT * FORM login`   your query is totally wrong its `FROM` not `Form`

Comment: This condition is useless `if($type=='Member'){
            ?>
            <script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>
            <?php
            } else {
                ?>
            <script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>
            <?php
            }`  it redirects users to the same page even if they not members

Comment: saving a password on a session very bad

Comment: @MasumBillah yours silence is not helping at all u have answers below

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors on your code here are they :

1. `$stmt->bindParam(1, username);`
2. `$stmt->bindParam(2, password);`
3. `$type = $row['type];`
4. `session_stat();`
5. Security Vulnerability `md5()` more especially that you are doing all this in a production server, you should use `password_hash()` and password_verify()` available on the php.net documentation.
6. and many more errors I just found as I look in your code, better add this line while you are still developing ` on top of every page so you can see all your errors, when you done on live server then remove that line. look at my comments for more errors.

This is how your login page should look with no errors;

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    header("location:dashboard.php"); // if the user is logged in already dont log themm in again, its gonna irritate them.
}
include "config.php";

if (isset($_POST['SubmitButtonName'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

        //return error to the user
    } else {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        try {

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username = ? ");
            $stmt->execute([$username]);
            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if (count($results) > 0) {
                //username is correct
                foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
                    //now verify password

                    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                        // password is correct
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                        $_SESSION['id']       = $row['id'];

                        if ($row['type'] == "Member") {

                            header("location:page.php");
                        } else {

                            //type not a member redirect to different page
                            header("location:AppropriatePage.php");
                        }

                    } else {
                        //password incorrect return proper message

                    }

                }

            } else {

                //user account does not exists return proper message
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {

            error_log("Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

    }

}
?>
```

> **NB: On your registration page remove this line `$password = md5($_POST['password']);` and replace with `$password =
>   Password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` and then
>   re-register when you are done you can login again.**
>
> Read Jay Blanchard's blog about proper password preparation in php
>   here :
>   http://www.jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html 
>   then for pdo prepared statements read Your Common Sense's blog here :
>   https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: This is not the answer- question is why page is not working, not to write a new script. Btw, you have too much if/else and i would never accept this sphagetti code.

Comment: When you answer questions you don't only focus on the OP, but also on future users with the same question @Vladd

Comment: Anyhow, your code is not the answer to question and its poorly written and it should never be example of how that should be done. You are downvoting everyone trying to get your answer accepted still providing bad code.

Comment: I'm not downvoting anyone and m not trying to get my answer to be accepted m just providing solution to OP, thanks for pointing out that my code is poorly writing in future I will try to write a better one

Comment: that is not solution. Where i can show you your code, but properly written and refactored of these indentations and sphagetties? I tried to paste it here, but cant, its too long for a comment

Comment: Thanks but not thanks I prefer my poorly written code than what u just gave me. @Vladd

Answer (score -1):

change session_stat();
 to session_start()

and make sure you on your display errors in php.ini file

Comment: he said his page is not loading. because he has wrote session_start spelling wrong. if display_error are not set it wont show any error

Comment: yea i know it , he has made lots of mistake. what mistake i have found i have said it  to him

Comment: please tell me, what mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in many typos and syntax errors and that is reason why your page not loading. Here fixed typos and syntax:

```
    include "config.php";
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? AND password=?"); //changed
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username); // changed
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $password); // changed
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $user = $row['username'];
        $pass = $row['password'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $type = $row['type']; /// you forgot \' here
    if ($username==$user && $pass==$password) {
        session_start(); // changed
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
        if($type=='Member'){
```

Comment: Man what are you doing? This is not supposed to be run but to replace part of OP code. Why you down voted me?? Are you serious?

Comment: still m not changing my DV there's nothing good about this answer